# ASP.NET expected ; error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code:

```
var defaultResult = $"Enum_{@this.GetType().Name}_{@this}";
```

but I get this error:

> expected ;

How do I fix this? String.Format?

Comment: Include some surrounding code, because this line is fine.

Comment: @kiziu Have you tried it? Because it's not.

Comment: @DrewKennedy nothing wrong with `$`, it marks an interpolated string. Besides the error is *not* about `$`

Comment: I am not famous of the `$` symbol, but I doubt if the `@` could be placed inside `{}`

Comment: @Drew, my bad, a lesson for the future.

Comment: @kiziu No worries. C# and .NET versions tend to be forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is a feature available in C# 6.0. Make sure you're set to the correct version.

Comment: The error doesn't mention `$` at all. The older compilers would complain about `$` not `;`

Comment: I'm on C# 5.0 and I got the error about needing a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation is supported onward c# 6.0. 
[read here for more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx)